# Extracting link when a nested div is present and a blank when there is no nested div using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, exception

I want to extract a list from the following html code, like:

```
[abc,xyz]
[def, ]
[ghi,xyzz]
```

Here is the html code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="a">
            <div class="b">abc</div>
            <div class="c"><a href="xyz"></a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="a">
            <div class="b">def</div>
        </div>
        <div class="a">
            <div class="b">ghi</div>
            <div class="c"><a href="xyzz"></a></div>
        </div>    
   </body>
</html>
```

And here is what I tried writing in python:

```
    elem = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("b")
    try:
        url = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='c']/a")
    except NoSuchElementException:
        url = ''
    i=0
    while i < 3:
        print [elem[i].text,url[i].get_attribute("href")]
        i += 1
```

But it doesn't fill the second element by a blank string, and I get an output like:

```
    [abc,xyz]
    [def,xyzz ]
    [ghi,]
```

How to fill a blank space in the list if there is no such nested division existing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the XPath in your `try/except` isn't getting an `NoSuchElementException` because it's finding two elements. You should instead first find your `div.a` elements and then find the `a` children of each of them:

```
elem = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('b')
divs = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('a')
url = []

for div in divs:
    links = div.find_elements_by_xpath('.//a')
    if len(links) > 0:
        url.append(links[0].get_attribute('href'))
    else:
        url.append('')
i=0

while i < 3:
    print [elem[i].text, url[i]]
    i += 1
```

This way you'll have your blank element for the second `div`.

**Update**: I originally was looking for `div` with class `"c"`, of which there are, similarly to the `<a>` tags, only two. Now updated to look for class `a` instead.

Comment: can you help me making the same list i mentioned in the starting of the question? I am trying the same from quite long now. :(

Comment: @drkthng can you help me in this question?

Comment: @PrabhjotRai try the latest update. Earlier I was looking for immediate children of `div.a` instead of descendants. Also, you had a problem in your initial code where you were looking to call `.get_attribute("href")` on an empty string, which would cause errors. Fixed above.